# Find out the only color in an image ?

Tags: colors, background

I have an image which is just made of one color ?  (it could be 1x1 image or 1900x1200 image is still one color)

How do I know which color is ?

For instance you could think the image is black but then you would learn that it's really
"020201"

or maybe you think the image is some kind of red but I Need to know if it is "FF0000" or 
"EE3030" and so on...

Comment: It would be useful to know what language you are trying to use to detect the color, and what you've tried.

Comment: open the file and peruse its data using the format of the file?

Comment: Tbh, I do not understand why this question is still open. It is so open ended that it isn't funny. @Zo72: What exactly are you talking about? C++? C#? SDL? Qt? Is it about programming at all? Are you a designer perhaps? Paint Shop Pro? What are you looking for? What have you tried? Have you tried anything at all? Which expertise do you have? Seriously, this question is crap; sorry, I mean Total Crap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq | http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to determine the color in a programming language, or can you use a tool/app to determine the color?

**Tools**

If you can use a tool or app, then use the "eye dropper" or "color picker" tool available in most graphics programs.

- If you're on windows, [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net) is a handy (and free) app with a [Color Picker](http://www.getpaint.net/doc/latest/ColorPicker.html) tool.  Use that to select the color, then click the "More" button in the Colors Window to see the hex value.
- If you would rather use your browser, Google your browser's name with "eye dropper" for plug-ins that should do the trick.  ex: "Chrome eye dropper"

**Code**

For the following snippets assume **file** is a reference to your image file, and the coordinates of the pixel you want to examine are **x** and **y**:

- In Java:

  ```
  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
  int rgb = image.getRGB(x,y);
  String hex = Integer.toHexString(rgb);
  ```
- In PHP:

  ```
  $image = imagecreatefrompng(file); // or use imagecreatefromjpeg(), etc.
  $rgb = imagecolorat($image, x, y);
  $hex = dechex($rgb);
  ```
- In C#:

  ```
  Bitmap image = new Bitmap(file);
  Color rgb = image.GetPixel(x, y);
  String hex = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(rgb);
  ```

Comment: @Zo72 : Out of curiosity, which part answered your OP?

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

- open the image in a hex-editor
- take a program that has a color-picker which works across application boundaries
- look into the SDL documentation
- look into the Qt documentation
- look into the Windows API documentation
- look into the Processing documentation
- look into your programming language's documentation
- look into the code that creates the image
- look into tcp packets that transmit the image
- look into wxWidgets documentation
- print the image and get a spectrometer
- look into the X documentation
- look into the GTK documentation
- look into the KDE documentation
- look into the DirectFB documentation
- look into the DirectX documentation
- look into the OpenGL documentation
- look into the OpenRT documentation
- look into the Lux Render documentation
- look into the PBRT documentation
- look into the Blender documentation
- look into the Reyes documentation
- look into the VTK documentation
- look into the ITK documentation

Hope this helps.